# Short guid in SQL Server / converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier

Tags: sql-server, guid

I need to create a column witch will contain short guid. So I found out something like this:

```
alter table [dbo].[Table]
add InC UNIQUEIDENTIFIER not null default LEFT(NEWID(),6)
```

But I get the error:

> Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.

I've been trying

```
LEFT(CONVERT(varchar(36),NEWID()),6)
```

and

```
CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,LEFT(CONVERT(varchar(36),NEWID()),6))
```

But I am still getting the same error.

Comment: I need guid that will contain only six symbols.

Comment: Or maybe i should just give varchar type to this column. Is this a good idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such thing as "short guid". Guid, or `uniqueidentifier` is a 16 byte data type. You can read about it [in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx). It means that the length must **always** be 16 bytes and you cannot use 6 characters as you are trying to do.

In the same MSDN article you can find description how you can initialize this type:

> A column or local variable of uniqueidentifier data type can be
>   initialized to a value in the following ways:
>
> - By using the NEWID function.
> - By converting from a string constant in    the form xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx, in which each x is a
>     hexadecimal digit in the range 0-9 or a-f. For example,
>     6F9619FF-8B86-D011-B42D-00C04FC964FF is a valid uniqueidentifier
>     value.

In your case you are trying to convert only 6 characters to `uniqueidentifier` which obviously fails.

If you want to use just 6 characters, just use `varchar(6)`:

```
alter table [dbo].[Table]
add InC varchar(6) not null default LEFT(NEWID(),6)
```

Keep in mind that in this case this guid is not guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot for your answer. And, do you know, if there are any way to create short guid in c#?

Comment: @Tatyana, you van mark this post if it answers your question

Answer (score 2):

Using `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM` instead of `NEWID` can improve random distribution of the string.

```
SELECT LEFT(CAST(CAST(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(16) AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER) AS VARCHAR(50)), 6)
```

Answer (score 1):

I just made this one since I couldn't find a good answer on the internet.

Please keep in mind this is a 64 bit representation of a 128bit value, so it has twice the collision possibilities that a real GUID would have. Does not handle 0.

Function takes a NEWID value: 6A10A273-4561-40D8-8D36-4D3B37E4A19C

and shortens it to : 7341xIlZseT

```
DECLARE @myid uniqueidentifier= NEWID()
select @myid
DECLARE @bigintdata BIGINT = cast(cast(reverse(NEWID()) as varbinary(max)) as bigint)
DECLARE @charSet VARCHAR(70) = '1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
DECLARE @cBase int = LEN(@charSet)
DECLARE @sUID varchar(22) = ''
DECLARE @x int

WHILE (@bigintdata <> 0)
BEGIN 
    SET @x = CAST(@bigintdata % @cBase as INT) + 1
    SET @bigintdata = @bigintdata / @cBase
    SET @sUID = SUBSTRING(@charSet, @x, 1) + @sUID;
END

SELECT @sUID
```

Comment: Is this reversible into the same GUID? if so, could give an example?

Answer (score 0):

I read all the answers and used "CrimsonMoose's" answer to solve my problem.
After modifying their codes and making them usable, I came up with the following codes :

```
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW GUIDView AS SELECT [GUID]=NEWID()
GO
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.CreateCompressedGUID()
RETURNS VARCHAR(11)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @result         VARCHAR(22) = '';
    DECLARE @keyGUID        BIGINT;
    DECLARE @resultChars    VARCHAR(70) = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    DECLARE @division       INT = LEN(@resultChars)
    DECLARE @divisionRemained int;
    SELECT @keyGUID=CAST(CAST(REVERSE([GUID]) AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS BIGINT) FROM GUIDView

    WHILE (@keyGUID <> 0)
    BEGIN 
        SET @divisionRemained = @keyGUID % @division;
        SET @divisionRemained = @divisionRemained + 1;
        SET @keyGUID = @keyGUID / @division;
        SET @result = SUBSTRING(@resultChars,@divisionRemained,1) + @result;
    END;

    RETURN @result;
END;
GO
SELECT Example = dbo.CreateCompressedGUID()
```